# Subset of infinite sequence proof

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a set of infinite sequences $(a_1, a_2...)$ in field $K$, prove that a subset $W$, consisting of those sequences having only a finite number of nonzero elements is a subspace of $V$.

I tried this:

since $W \subseteq V$, and $V$ is a vector space, a basis of $W$ is an independent set in $V$, so $dim(W) \le dim(V)$

Don't really know what to do next

edit:  subset $W$, consisting of those sequences having only a finite number of nonzero elements

Comment: Should $V$ and $W$ be assumes as vector spaces?

Comment: I think you may mean: Let $V$ be the vector space (over  a field $K)$ of all infinite sequences of members of $K,$ and let $W=\lbrace (a_1, a_2, \dots)\in V\mid \text{ only finitely many of the }a_k\text{  are non-zero}\rbrace.$  Then $W$ is a subspace of $V.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't talk about a basis for $W$ before you proved that $W$ is indeed a subspace (and so, in particular, a vector space). To do that, you need to check whether the following three things hold:

1. The zero vector of $V$ belongs to $W$ ($0_V \in W$).
2. If $w_1,w_2 \in W$ then $w_1 + w_2 \in W$.
3. If $\lambda \in K$ and $w \in W$ then $\lambda w \in W$.

In your case, the zero vector of $V$ is an infinite sequence whose members are all $0$ and so it belongs to $W$. If $w_1,w_2 \in W$, let us write

$$ w_1 = (a_1, \dots, a_k, \dots), w_2 = (b_1, \dots, b_k, \dots). $$

By definition of $W$ there exists $N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n > N_1$ then $a_n = 0$ and similarly there exists $N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n > N_2$ then $b_n = 0$. This implies that if $n > \max\{N_1,N_2\}$ then $a_n + b_n = 0$ and since

$$ w_1 + w_2 = (a_1 + b_2, \dots, a_k + b_k, \dots) $$

only finitely many elements of $w_1 + w_2$ are non-zero and so $w_1 + w_2 \in W$. I leave the verification of $(3)$ to you.